# Is it possible to retrieve build definition ID related to a work item using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

The requirement is to fetch all the work items between different releases and create a report. The list of work items can be fetched using below API call.

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{projectName}/_apis/release/releases/{currentReleaseId}/workitems??api-version=6.0&baseReleaseId={baseReleaseId}
```

**Now, for each of this work item, we also need to know the build version when it is delivered.** I'm not able to find any entries related to build/release in the work item data fetched using

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/_apis/wit/workItems/{ID}
```

Is there any relationship between work item tasks and respective build or release definition ID when it was delivered?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT - Thanks for the solution flow. I have accepted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve build definition ID related to a work item using Azure DevOps REST API?

The answer is yes.

You could use the REST API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) with `$expand` to get the commit links:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=relations&api-version=6.0
```

Then you would see the `commits` in relations part of the response body:

[image]

Then we could use the REST API [Statuses API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for Commit. It seems that when starting and ending build, the appropriate status is posted.

So when we call

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/statuses?api-version=6.0
```

We will get all last builds associated with the Commit and their statuses.